# VS 2013 and Lync sdk 2013

Tags: sdk, visual-studio-2013, lync

Are VS 2013 and Lync sdk 2013 not compatible with each other ? i am getting error while installing sdk.
it says vs 2010 sp1 or above required. anyone else tried the same ?

Comment: I don't know about Lync SDK, but UCMA (both Lync 2010 and 2013) Development works on VS2013. You could try manually extracting the files from the installer and simply referencing the Lync SDK DLL in your project.

Comment: @WillemDuncan thanks it works as you sayed.

Answer (score 3):

What solved my problem was: with 7zip extracted the content from the installer, and then installed the correct version (x86 or x64).

After that opened Visual Studio, created a new WPF application and in the view went to the toolbox. 
All the controls from Lync were there ready to use.

Visual studio templates (if they exist) were the only thing that I didn't manage to find/install.

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

The install does say "or higher," but it lies. VS2013 is not supported.

[image: Lync 2013 SDK Install Error]

Answer (score 2):

True. 
The Lync 2013 SDK docs on MSDN also specify VS 2010 SP1 or VS2012. See this url: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj933215.aspx

A note on one of the microsoft forums suggests an upgrade is in the work and will be published soon.

Answer (score 1):

From the download page, I don't see the "or above" mentioned anywhere, they're very explicit on the version of Visual Studio to be installed.

> The following requirements must be met before developing applications
>   with Lync SDK.
>
> - Visual Studio 2010 RTM for Microsoft Windows Forms or WPF development.
> - Visual Studio 2010 SP1 for Silverlight development.
> - Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 or later service pack.
> - Microsoft Silverlight 5.0 runtime.
> - Microsoft Silverlight 5 Tools for Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36824

Answer (score 0):

Error message when you install Lync 2013 SDK on a computer that is running Visual Studio 2013:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2918796

Although, I'm not sure how you install the SDK first, since it requires the SilverLight tools, which requre the SDK .. which... 0_o